# Upload array of files Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I want to upload an array of files,in Laravel , and I am not sure what is the path and who to store the file. Eight now the data are stored ,but in my case the path is #. In the image  below I have the data that I am sending from front (Vuejs and I am using vue-upload-component)

[image]

```
$fileName = [];

foreach($request->input('files') as $files){
       $contractFile = new ContractFile();
       $contractFile->fill([
           'contract_id'   => $contract->id,
           'name'          => $files['name'],
           'path'          => '#',
       ])->save();
}
```

**ContractFile**

```
class ContractFile extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = ['path','contract_id','name'];

    public function contract()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(Contract::class);
    }

}
```

**ContractFile db**

```
    Schema::create('contract_files', function (Blueprint $table) {
    $table->bigIncrements('id');
    $table->integer('contract_id');
    $table->string('path');
    $table->string('name');
    $table->timestamps();
});
```

**filesystems.php**

```
'uploads' =>[
    'driver' => 'local',
    'root' => storage_path().'file/uploads',
],
```

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
foreach($request->file('files') as $uploadedFile){

      $filename = time() . '_' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();

       $path = $uploadedFile->store($filename, 'uploads');

       $contractFile = new ContractFile();
       $contractFile->contract_id = $contract->id;
       $contractFile->name = $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalName();
       $contractFile->path = $path;
       $contractFile->save();

}
```

> By default, the public disk uses the local driver and stores these
>   files in `storage/app/public`. To make them accessible from the web, you
>   should create a symbolic link from public/storage to
>   storage/app/public.

To create the [symbolic link](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/filesystem), **you should** use the storage:link Artisan command:

```
php artisan storage:link
```

Comment: Thanks, but I got this. Call to a member function getClientOriginalName() on array

Comment: Could you dump($request->input('files')) ??

Comment: did you tried $request->files instead of $request->input('files')

Comment: No errors now, but the data is not stored, neither data in db.

Comment: Pls add your  contractFile table schema and ContractFile Model

Comment: what is the difference between contract_id and id ?

Comment: Id is his ID, and contract_id is the if of the contract (each contract can have manyFiles), the problem is from getClientOriginalName, if I change a little , it works, but I get an error about the original name.

Comment: BTW. Content-Type: application/json. I read that I should use 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data', but then I get error 422.(for required fields from form, but are not empty.)

Comment: Check Updated answer

Comment: No error, not working, and I try with multipart also, but I get 422.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207359/discussion-between-foued-moussi-and-beusebiu).

Answer (score 0):

In form add file input something like:

```html
<input type="file" multiple name="attachments[]">
```

Then in controller action handle an array of uploaded files like:

```php
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage;
use Illuminate\Support\Str;

// Check if there are files uploadeded for the form name attribute.
if ($request->files->has('attachments')) {
    // Here we get the uploaded fileBag by attribute.
    $fileBag = $request->files->get('attachments');

    // Directory path where to upload the files.
    $dirPath = 'attachments'

    // Loop over each file in the bag to store.
    foreach ($fileBag as $uploadedFile) {
        // Create unique file name. You can write your logic but recommend 
        // using uuid to avoid name collision. Make sure to add same 
        // extension as uploaded file.
        $fileName = (string) Str::uuid() . '.' . $uploadedFile->getClientOriginalExtension();

        // Store using Storage Facades.
        // Note: storing using request->file->store() will clear files array 
        // after first store call and since we are looping here that won't 
        // work.
        $path = Storage::putFileAs($dirPath, $uploadedFile, $fileName);
        
        // Now you can use the path and store it in the DB table or any way 
        // you want.
    }
}
```

For more configuration refer: [Laravel 7.x File Storage](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/filesystem#main-content), [Symfony File Bag](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.1/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/FileBag.php), [Symfony Uploaded File](https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/6.2/src/Symfony/Component/HttpFoundation/File/UploadedFile.php)